# How to get current page number of pdf document which embed to meteor app by <embed> tag?

Tags: javascript, html, pdf, meteor

I am trying to get current page number of pdf which I embed to my meteor app by `<embed/>` tag.
I embed pdf like this :

It renders pdf to my app greatly. But I can not get current page number ?
I have searched older questions on stackoverflow but I can't get any result. Any ideas?

Comment: Probably not possible. Browsers use different ways of rendering a PDF in an embed tag, and I'm not aware of any such API in any of them.

Comment: What about <object> tag or pdfOject.js ?

Comment: Same with object, not idea how pdfObject.js works, but if it uses object or embed, probably not. *Might* be possible with Mozilla's PDF.js.